# Add a new column by mutate involving a conditional

Tags: r, dplyr

I need to add a new column in dplyr by mutate involving an conditional. I can't find a way to implement the following scheme in the tidyverse, but I can do it Excel. That makes me feel like something of a barbarian. Does someone know how to accomplish this in the tidyverse?

- The first value of the running count column is 1, no matter what is in the "n" column.
- After the first row, here is the conditional. If the n column=1, the running.count output is the running.count value from the row above +1. If the n column=0, the running.count output is the running.count value from the row above +1 only when it is the first 0 after a 1 in the "n" column. Otherwise, it is just the running.count value from the row above.

Here's some toy data with the desired output:

```r
data.frame("n"=c(0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1),"running.count"=c(1,2,3,3,3,3,4,5,6,7))
```

[image: This is the output.]

Comment: The condition is not clear

Comment: Sorry about that. I clarified it a bit.

Comment: Can you try `library(dplyr); library(data.table);df1 %>% group_by(running.count = rleid(n) ) %>% mutate(ind = if(all(n==1)) duplicated(n) else FALSE) %>% ungroup %>% mutate(running.count = running.count + ind) %>% select(-ind)`

Comment: Also, please show the expected for `"n"=c(0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1)`

Comment: Yes, that works for me. Thank you. I will need to study how you did this...

Comment: Can you please show the expected for the one i commented so that it can be generalized

Comment: @akrun "running.count"=c(1,2,3,3,4,5,6,7,8,9))

Comment: Try `df2 %>% group_by(running.count = rleid(n) ) %>% mutate(ind = if(all(n==1))  row_number() - 1 else 0) %>% ungroup %>% mutate(running.count = rleid(running.count, ind)) %>% select(-ind)`

Comment: the second code should give the expected output

Comment: @akrun That looks correct to me. I would mark it as answered, but I don't see how to do that for you. Thank you so much!!

Comment: Or `cumsum(c(1, diff(n) != 0 | n[-1] == 1))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `rleid` from `data.table` to create the running.count column

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
df1 %>% 
   group_by(running.count = rleid(n) ) %>% 
   mutate(ind = if(all(n==1))  row_number() - 1 else 0) %>% 
   ungroup %>% 
   mutate(running.count = rleid(running.count, ind)) %>% 
   select(-ind)
# A tibble: 10 x 2
#       n running.count
#   <dbl>         <int>
# 1     0             1
# 2     1             2
# 3     0             3
# 4     0             3
# 5     0             3
# 6     0             3
# 7     1             4
# 8     0             5
# 9     1             6
#10     1             7
```

#### data

```
df1 ,- structure(list(n = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1)), 
   class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```